# how to run parallel test in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have 15 feature tests in the project. this information of env.test:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test_db
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

when I run my test as parallel using `php artisan test --parallel` i get with error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Settlement\PublicSTest::testCreatePublicS
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied to create database (SQL: create database "test_db_test_3" encoding "utf8")
```

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#parallel-testing-and-databases) states, `Laravel` will create multiple databases to avoid the parallel processes colliding with each others data.

Add the privilege for the user to create databases, assuming this is an `postgres` database based on the error.

Access cli

```
psql test_db test
```

Command to execute

```
ALTER USER test CREATEDB;
```